# How can I 'change in number' or 'change in digits' in Vim

Tags: vim, numbers, editor

I'm regularly editing CSS in Vim and need to change a value like:

```
width: 300px;
```

to something else like:

```
width: 178px;
```

Normally what I do is navigate to the 3 in 300 and type `cw` to change the word. But if I do this I have to type the `px` bit again. Is there a short and quick way to say `change in digits`.

In my searching I've discovered Ctrl-a and Ctrl-x to increment and decrement numbers in this situation. Is there an equivalent for being able to retype the number?

I should clarify that the ideal solution would require the fewest keystrokes at time of operation and support modifications to different length numbers. Like if I wanted to change 300px to 17px.

Comment: Why not navigate to the 3 in 300 and use the R command?

Comment: I clarified my question a bit to help explain why this isn't ideal. In some cases I want to change 300px to 17px. If I was just using R to do this I would need to type extra characters to handle the final 0 `R17ESCx`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is `in`, a custom text-object that lets you act on numerical values (including floats):

```
" custom text-object for numerical values
function! Numbers()
    call search('\d\([^0-9\.]\|$\)', 'cW')
    normal v
    call search('\(^\|[^0-9\.]\d\)', 'becW')
endfunction
xnoremap in :<C-u>call Numbers()<CR>
onoremap in :normal vin<CR>
```

The actual search is performed in a function to avoid clobbering the search register and search highlighting.

You can add that text-object to your `vimrc` "as is" and use it like other text-objects:

```
vin
cin
yin
din
```

[image: demo]

--- edit ---

This new version:

- doesn't mess with search highlighting (good),
- doesn't mess with the search register (good),
- respects BOL and EOL (good),
- works with floats (good).

Comments welcome.

--- edit ---

Comment: This is a nice solution. However, if `hlsearch` is set, `vin` highlights everything in the current file that is not a digit or period.

Comment: This fails if the number under the cursor is the first or last thing on the line; in both cases it includes the newline adjacent to the number.

Comment: Replacing the `xnoremap` line with `xnoremap in ?[^\.0-9]<CR>/.<CR>o/[^\.0-9]<CR>?.<CR>` fixes the newline problem.

Comment: Nice. I would suggest swapping the two search lines, so that it searches forwards first and then backwards. That way, if the cursor is not currently on a digit, it will search forward in the current line for the next number instead of backward. That matches the behavior of the other text object commands, and it's more useful generally—it allows the user to type `vin` while the cursor is in the word `width` in the CSS example above, and it selects the number following the width.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a "change in digits" command, but you can use `t`, which is like `f` but goes to the character before what you are searching for; that is, if you type `tp`, it will move the cursor to the character just before "p" in your line. Combining it with `c`, if your cursor is on the 3, `ctp178 Esc` will replace 300 with 178.

Alternatively, you can use `3s` to substitute the next three characters: `3s178 Esc`. This is easy when the string being replaced is easy to scan for length. And if your replacement text is the same length as the text being replaced, you can just use `R` to replace: `R178 Esc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the text object proposed by *romainl*, or, alternatively, rely on existing ones:

- https://github.com/tkhren/vim-textobj-numeral
- https://github.com/haya14busa/vim-textobj-number (with `an`, `in`)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the 300 to 178 on that line do:

`:s/300/178/` RETURN

It will do a find->replace **on the current line**

To do it globally, do:

`:%s/300/178/g` RETURN

Comment: Having to retype the `300` makes this very inconvenient

Comment: @DenysSéguret `:s//178/` will reuse the last search pattern.

Comment: This is still far from answering the question

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way is to use visual mode, so I would navigate to the 3, then use either 2 spaces (or any other motion command) to navigate to the end of the part I wanted to change.  Once I have highlighted the part I want to change, just type s178 to substitute the chars "178" for whatever is highlighted.